# What does #ifdef _CH_ preprocessor directive do in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, ch

Specifically, what is `_CH_`? I'm pretty sure it is related to some sort of `#include` safety.

This is the form of the code I found in a header file:

```
#ifndef FOOBAR_H
#define FOOBAR_H

// Function prototypes

#ifdef _CH_
#pragma importf "foobar.c"
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: [Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/) ?

Comment: it becomes `1` if you are using a CH. then execute `#pragma importf "foobar.c"` then `foobar.c` is loaded in this place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CH` is a C/C++ interpreter. Information about it can be found [here](https://www.softintegration.com/) and is described as:

> "Ch is the most complete, cross-platform C interpreter and scripting engine in existence.".

It appears that the check for `_CH_` is to determine if a `C` file is being processed under `CH`. In this case if it was being processed by `CH` then it would process the line `#pragma importf "foobar.c"`.

From what I can tell from the `CH` [documentation](https://www.softintegration.com/support/faq/generalprog.html) the `#pragma importf` imports another file:

> search module1.c in current directory first, then directories specified in _fpath

In our case it would search for "foobar.c" and import it.

In environments other than `CH`, `_CH_` wouldn't be defined and the statements in the `#ifdef _CH_` block are ignored.

Comment: Thanks! This was code from a professor, why am I not surprised that it would be in relation to some proprietary software?

Comment: The only other time I have ever seen reference to CH was with regards to Lego Mindstorm robotics. It seems to have a niche market including academia.